# Long Continous Beep with ASUS motherboard

Tags: motherboard

I just built a computer.  I connected everything properly but when I boot the computer I get a  long continous beep, that does not stop. The BIOS loads up, there are no errors, and everything works fine. There is nothing in the manual that explains the ***beep*** I am getting.

***Computer Configuration:***

- Motherboard: Asus M5A88-M
- Video Card: Asus EAH5830
- RAM: 4 Gigs of DDR3
- CPU: AMD Athlon II 3.4 Ghz
- Hardrive: SATA

Does anyone have any ideas what the beep is for or a reference where I can figure it out myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a long solid beep indicates one of two things - an overheating problem, or more likely given your description a stuck key.  Try fooling with the keyboard and see what happens.

Comment: There is still a beap, when the keyboard is still not connected.

Comment: But how do I solve overheating problem, there are 3 fans, but they are  not connected to the motherboard.

Comment: @PiezoSYstems Connect the fans to the motherboard, then. See your motherboard's manual for instructions.

Comment: There are no slots, it has a CPU Fan which is connected, and there is one more a CHA Fan, however the heads on CPU Fans can only connect to Power Supply.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a memory error.  According to the Award POSTs (I believe this is your BIOS) .

http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/awardbeep.htm#

In some cases you can put one memory stick in at a time.  Possibly a dry blow of air on the bottom of the memory stick has worked for me in the past too.

Comment: This (looking up the beep code via the manufacturer) is the correct answer, not sure why the other was accepted.

Comment: Agreed, if this is actually the case I don't know why my answer was accepted.  As I stated, I didn't actually look this up - it's pretty unusual that a solid beep would be memory but if that's what it is, that's what it is. I've upvoted this.